# Undefined offset:1

Tags: php, laravel, undefined

```
        $aa = Input::get('AccountOpeningDate' . $i);
        $dateinfo = explode("-", $aa);
        $testDay = Carbon::createFromDate($dateinfo[0], $dateinfo[1], 
        $dateinfo[2], 'UTC');
        $actualDate = $testDay->setTimezone('+6:00');
```

when I run this code then I get an output.But it cause an error that like the image below.

[image]

```
ErrorException in MemberController.php line 532:
Undefined offset: 1
in MemberController.php line 532
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\timf\app\Http\Controllers\MemberController.php', '532', array('id' => '4001-5088-0565', 'memberdata' => object(Member), 'somityDay' => object(Zone1), 'i' => '2', 'aa' => '', 'dateinfo' => array(''), 'testDay' => object(Carbon), 'actualDate' => object(Carbon), 'producttype' => '2', 'memberaccount' => object(Accountstable), 'valsa' => object(Product), 'AccNameSub' => 'MSSM', 'accnumber' => 'MSSM.4001-5088-0565', 'k' => '13', 'SavingSetup' =>
```

This code is written in laravel 5.1.

Comment: looks like your $dateinfo variable is an empty array.

Comment: Please check for the exact issue, same question you had asked within few hours

Comment: Your input is probably empty as i dont see any value in your array. Check $aa by placing dd($aa); if its empty than there will be your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have already solved the problem

Comment: If you are no longer seeking assistance for this question, you may delete your question (as long as no one submits an answer).  This means volunteers won't waste time reading your question, volunteer moderators won't have to consider closing/deleting the page, and you will regain any lost rep points (furthermore, your SO account won't have a downvoted question attached to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $aa = Input::get('AccountOpeningDate' . $i);
```

Here $aa has no data in case of any conditions. So the array $dateinfo remaining empty. I have fixed the problem by ensuring $aa data not empty.
      now the code is running well.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a comma missing in your first line of code.